# Authenticating requests from App Engine to Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

There are several questions on this topic, but it seems like most of those use-cases are around Firebase.

I've got a simple Node/Express app running on App Engine. I've got several cron jobs scheduled there that call some Cloud Functions in the same project. I'd like to configure my Cloud Functions to only accept requests from that App Engine service.

Based on Google's Cloud Function documentation, is it as simple of something like this?

```
exports.myFunction = (req, res) => {
  // Set CORS headers for preflight requests

  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://my-app-engine-project.appspot.com');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
  } else {
    // The rest of my cloud function logic goes here
  }
};
```

I'm unclear on what I need to pass from my App Engine route to authorize everything successfully.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm trying to do something similar. App Engine sending requests to authenticated Cloud Functions but I can't figure out how to let App Engine in.

Comment: @Ari - I ended up using a combination of Cloud Scheduler and Cloud Pub/Sub instead of App Engine.

Comment: I ended up figuring how to do it, there's some google documentation about it, confusing but managed to secure the cloud functions and have only my App Engine server authenticate.

Comment: @Ari so how did that work? Where did you find the docs? Thanks!

Comment: @WillemMulder I can't remember exactly, but its very similar to what the commenter posted. The docs here as well https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating

Comment: @Ari all right, thanks!